# How to refer to other Styled Components when using MUI styled function and Styled Components?

Tags: material-ui, babeljs, styled-components, vite, emotion

How should I refer to other Styled Components when using MUI styled function and Styled Components? This is the intended syntax:

```
const Parent = styled('div')({
  "&:hover": {
    [`${Child}`]: {
      color: 'red'
    }
  }
});
```

If I try to use the code above I get this error:

`Component selectors can only be used in conjunction with @emotion/babel-plugin, the swc Emotion plugin, or another Emotion-aware compiler transform.`

If I install the `@emotion/babel-plugin` and configure the plugin in the vite config file as suggested [here](https://github.com/mui/material-ui/issues/29121#issuecomment-945416073) I still get the same error.

(I also tried importing "@emotion/babel-plugin" without speciying options as in [here](https://dev.to/glocore/configure-emotion-with-your-vite-react-project-7jl) or passing the options to the babel plugin and still failed)

This is my `vite.config.ts`:

```
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    eslint(),
    react({
      babel: {
        plugins: [
          // "@emotion/babel-plugin"
          [
            "@emotion",
            // "@emotion/babel-plugin", <<< as an alternative also doesn't work
            {
              importMap: {
                "@mui/material/styles": {
                  styled: {
                    canonicalImport: ["@emotion/styled", "default"],
                    styledBaseImport: ["@mui/material/styles", "styled"]
                  }
                },
                "@mui/system": {
                  styled: {
                    canonicalImport: ["@emotion/styled", "default"],
                    styledBaseImport: ["@mui/system", "styled"]
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        ]
      },
      jsxImportSource: "@emotion/react"
    }),
    tsconfigPaths()
  ],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      "@mui/styled-engine": "@mui/styled-engine-sc"
    }
  },
});
```

**Should I switch from Styled Components to Emotion if I want to use this feature?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your question:

> Should I switch from Styled Components to Emotion if I want to use this feature?

If you do not need Emotion-specific features, importing `styled` from `@mui/material/styles` will help you avoid adding another package to your bundle and allow you to take advantage of the [benefits for theming](https://mui.com/system/styled/#what-problems-does-it-solve). Otherwise, Emotion will be fine.

---

### Some background

I have tried using `@emotion/styled`, `@mui/system/styled`, `@mui/material/styles`, `@mui/styled-engine`, and `@mui/styled-engine-sc` with the template literal component selector syntax. None of them worked.

However, component selector syntax worked for me when style objects were used with `@emotion/styled` and `@mui/material/styles`:

```
const Parent = styled('div')( () => {
    return (
        {
            [`${Child}`]: {
                border: '2px solid red',
                backgroundColor: 'purple'
            }
        }
    );
} );
```

Using `@mui/styled-engine-sc` with component selector syntax within a style object rendered the Parent and Child components. But, `@mui/styled-engine-sc` did not respect some CSS cascading rules, and did not properly implement some of the [styled API options](https://mui.com/system/styled/#api).

Comment: it turns out I'm having a storybook issue, not a mui issue. importing from `@mui/material/styles` just works out of the box in normally rendered components. I should have checked first :P

Answer (score 2):

My solution is similar to that of @kofeigen. Using MUI v5. Snippet first:

```
import { styled } from "@mui/system";
// This works as well:
// import { styled } from "@mui/material/styles";

const Child = () => <div/>;

const Parent = styled("div")({
  [`&:hover ${Child}`]: {
    background: 'black',
  },
});
```

The difference is that you can use `@mui/system/styled`, or `@mui/material/styles`. To get it to work, you need to use `@emotion/babel-plugin` like you did, and add the following configuration to your `babel.config.js` (seems that you've used the correct one):

```js
plugins: [
  [
    "@emotion",
    {
      importMap: {
        "@mui/system": {
          styled: {
            canonicalImport: ["@emotion/styled", "default"],
            styledBaseImport: ["@mui/system", "styled"]
          }
        },
        "@mui/material/styles": {
          styled: {
            canonicalImport: ["@emotion/styled", "default"],
            styledBaseImport: ["@mui/material/styles", "styled"]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ]
]
```

As of today, this config is documented [here](https://mui.com/system/styled/#how-to-use-components-selector-api). In my case I needed to add this config to Storybook, which on 6.5.x boils down to:

```js
babel: async (options) => ({
  ...options,
 plugins: [/* your code here*/]
}),
```